# How do we find a better forum?

Tags: discussion

I have been a Stack Overflow user for many years now, and have been overall very happy with the experience. I am all in favor of directing users to a better forum to answer their question, but telling a user "go find a better forum" is NOT helpful.

I asked a design question for a Windows form. No, there is no specific programming question involved, it was a question of design, specifically about a .NET Windows application. But when I look at https://stackexchange.com/sites, it really isn't clear where I am supposed to go.

Do I just join every site with the word "Programming" and hope for the best? If you think a question isn't appropriate for a specific forum, you should at least have some helpful suggestion for the user as to where he should post instead. Or maybe, there should be a place to ask the question, "What forum should I choose to ask this question?" like Microsoft has.

I would rather use this site than Microsoft's sites any day. ALL they want to do there is tell you that you are posting in the wrong place. I always thought this site was a little more user friendly.

Comment: So, it's MY responsibility to hunt down where YOUR question goes? If it's off-topic here, I consider that my responsibility stops at telling you it's off-topic here.

Comment: So every user of every site is obligated to have an intimate understanding of the scope of every single site?  Most people are only active on one site, maybe two or three, and would only know what's on topic on those few sites.

Comment: @Servy UNACCEPTABLE! You should also know of ALL the suggestions in Area 51 so you can tell people which site in the future might be good for their question. COME ON (/end of obvious sarcasm)

Comment: @Patrice I didn't say SE sites.  I meant the entire internet, duh.

Comment: WOW. Even more hostility here then where I posted my question. Clearly, I misunderstood the purpose of Stack Exchange, I thought it was for developers to help other developers. For example, I use SharePoint StackExchange a lot. I would direct any SharePoint question over to there, because we are more focused on programming against SharePoint. Why is the idea of being helpful such a bad thing? Better yet, what about creating a forum specifically to ask what forum to join? It's one of the few good ideas Microsoft has about their site.

Comment: You need to research before asking here, and that includes researching whether you should be asking here, elsewhere on SE (e.g. [ux.se], in this case) or somewhere completely different. You're right that you can't expect people to know all of the sites in the network, but that goes for *the people closing the questions* as well as those asking them! *"I thought it was for developers to help other developers"* - yes, but not with *everything*...

Comment: So, asking a question that tries to help us to be more user friendly gets me nothing but downvotes.

Comment: @CigarDoug So you're assuming that all of the people that see your questions know what other site it's on topic for but are refusing to tell you, rather than them simply not knowing what site it actually belongs on?  What's your basis for that assumption?

Comment: Downvotes on meta are different! they don't cost you rep and are WAY more easily thrown around

Comment: @CigarDoug You're not asking people to be more friendly, you're demanding that they do things for you that are not reasonable expectations of other people.  (Which is quite unfriendly yourself, by the way.)

Comment: @CIgarDoug the hostility you feel is because your question feels like a rant, and at the same time, it feels like you're asking US to tell you "hey it's off-topic here, but I went to hunt down where it goes on topic and it's here". If the only SE site I use is SO, and I know it's off-topic here, should I refrain from telling you "don't post here" because I don't know where you should post? Shouldn't it be your responsibility as a user to find where your question goes?

Comment: I gave an example of a site I am familiar with, I would presume that most of us on Stack Exchange use more than one site. So yes, if I saw a question and I knew a better forum, I would suggest it.

Comment: Well, partly it's a rant, so at least I knew to bring it here. But also, it was a question about where do I go when I have no idea what forum to use. It looks like ryanuyu answered me.

Comment: @CigarDoug 1. That's not a reasonable assumption; most people use just one site 2. You're demanding that every single off topic question be directed to the appropriate site, and assuming that in every single case someone who saw it knows where it goes.  That's not at all the case; it's very likely that none of the people who saw the question are active on another site where it belongs. 3. Lots of off topic questions aren't on topic on *any* SE site, so there is no other site to direct the user to.

Comment: @CigarDoug yes, YOU know ONE other site, you say it yourself. So if I ask a question on Stack that is CLEARLY not on-topic but should go to, let's say, to Programmers. Since you don't know Programmers, will you simply stand and let my question on Stack or tell me it doesn't belong there?  Also, you admit yourself this is partly a rant. People don't take kindly to rants. You can (and should) post in a neutral tone...

Comment: @Patrice Clearly he's going to look through the scope of every single site to go figure out where it does belong, so he can direct the user to the correct place, because doing anything else is being hostile.

Comment: Maybe I do expect more out of people, yes. I try to be helpful, in the real world and in the cyber one.

Comment: I completely understand telling someone off that is asking a question that can't be answered, or someone who is clearly looking for a homework answer. I was asking a valid question, and I asked it in the site where I THOUGHT it was appropriate.

Comment: @Servy: Just direct it to Yahoo answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99467

Comment: *"if I saw a question and I knew a better forum, I would suggest it"* - that's perfectly reasonable, and I think most people *do* do that. However, making it a *requirement* to know of a better place before you're allowed to comment or vote on a question is completely unreasonable.

Comment: It's not just telling someone off with a bad question. If it's a good question, but clearly off-topic for Stack, and I do not know WHERE it should go, I don't believe it my responsibility to do your "homework" of finding out where it actually goes. If I know it, I will gladly tell you. If I don't, tough luck.

Comment: And this question IS appropriate here, I don't see why you think it isn't. It's not closed, people are not telling you it's off-topic. The only thing is you get downvotes. Downvotes on meta mean disagreement more than anything

Comment: Well, using the Meta site is a new experience for me. I just knew enough to come here to ask the question.

Comment: Meta does require a tougher hide. Downvoting here doesn't mean "your question is bad!" it just means "yeah I don't agree with what you say". There's also more lenience in comments and jokes within them. I'm happy you stuck around for longer to GET that... a lot of new users to Meta don't

Comment: i posted an idea for your GUI over on your question. Doesn't take up real estate on your GUI, permanently

Comment: **[Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773)**

Comment: It sounds like you have a consistent problem with posting topics on the wrong forums and then being upset when you are informed about it. Perhaps you should look into why that keeps happening?

Comment: Consistent? OK, one is consistent. Got it.

Comment: So not only do you want me to solve your problem for you after you having done no research on the topic, if I can't answer your question because you asked it on the wrong site because you didn't do any research, you want me to *also* solve the problem of where your question actually belongs (if anywhere).... because you don't want to do research on the topic? It seems like 1) you really like it when other people solve your problems for you, and 2) you really don't like doing research.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Or maybe, there should be a place to ask the question, "What forum should I choose to ask this question?"

Meta (here) or the over meta [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) are appropriate places to ask for a [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) for your proposed question.  Include your question (or at least a good summary) in the meta post.  Just keep in mind that there isn't always an appropriate SE site for every question.  Some questions are inherently bad fits for the Q&A format and would be off-topic on any SE site.

Answer (score 11):

> I always thought this site was a little more user friendly.
>
> So, asking a question that tries to help us to be more user friendly gets me nothing but downvotes

Some of the easiest ways to get downvotes on Stack Exchange, in general, are:

- Be confrontational/critical about the site (bonus downvotes if you call users trolls/etc)
- Write rants
- Call SE a forum (Q/A is NOT a forum)
- Act entitled to anything (everyone here is a volunteer)
- Don't approach things with an attitude of "I'm trying to learn"
- Act immature

That you received "hostility" here should be no surprise to you, in light of these factors

Comment: "Complaining about receiving downvotes" is also another good way to attract downvotes. So is "please don't downvote" and "please upvote".